# Transparent NSButton shown with unwanted backgroundColor

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, nsview, nsbutton

So I have an `NSView` in which I created some borderless buttons programmatically.

Although I set their `backgroundColor` property to desired color, they show up like they have a darker shade.

[image: How could this be happening?]

Comment: Are you positive that is not the color you expect?  Try using Digital Color Meter.app (built-into macOS), to check the color to see if it's not the RGB values you inputted.  The colorspace is also relevant, it could be that it is different from what you are expecting

Comment: Thank's for your comment! Considering what you say, it may be something more I have to deal with, regarding the backgroundColor property of the NSButton instance. I also use a NSLabel entitled 'Choose a device' for which I also set the background color to be the same as the view's. I have no problem there.

Comment: Try setting the `backgroundColor` for the button to white, what do you see?

Comment: I would like to suggest clearing the background color of label and button. you will avoid this issue completely.

Comment: +1 for @Hashmat. You provided nearly no close (much less IB definition) of anything. Maybe you set the color in IB to something not available by default in UIColor. Maybe you set the alpha value to something in code that is giving you the visual output you are seeing. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: Okay, this works great programmatically and from storyboard interaction, but when I put the created NSView inside a NSScrollView, the problem goes back to it's initial state.

Comment: As others said before, try using `NSColor.clearColor` (also selectable in Interface Builder) for the button. Also, make sure that the button's appearance is Aqua, not vibrant.

Answer (score 7):

I guess that is the background of Label, not of Button, which does not appear when users choose to reduce transparency in System Preferences.

In that case, I have solved by this line of code:

```
myButton.appearance = NSAppearance(named: .aqua)
```

Comment: In my specific scenario, the fixed appearance of the light mode on the buttons improved the low contrast when in the dark mode. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here How I would do it as I mentioned in comment.
The custom view is connected as iboutlet and given green color.
Label has by default no back ground color.
The button has no border and of type Round Rect as you see in screen shot.
The blue color around button is the selection/ active control, but you can get rid of that too.

```
self.testBtn.focusRingType = NSFocusRingTypeNone;
```

[image]

edit add new image showing scroll bar:
[image]

Comment: Okay, thank's for your reply.  I also have to put the NSView inside a NSScrollView and this makes the problem reappear. Any sugestions to that?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I just put that view inside scroll view and haven't changed anything. and it's scrolling fine no color shade or whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

//set background color

```
button.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor]
```

//then set tint color of button

```
[btn setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```